# Can't install gem mysql on OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I can't install mysql gem on my 10.8 (mac osx) machine. I installed mysql with homebrew by

$brew install mysql

then I do:

```
$sudo gem install mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
/Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:894:in `block in have_func'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:893:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:50:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

any idea what to do?

Comment: Do you have MySQL development files/libraries installed for your OS?

Answer (score 2):

Did you have mysql installed before you upgraded to Mountain Lion? I had the same problem and this fixed it:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql
gem install mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a C compiler to compile some of the native extensions. (This is a Ruby requirement. You'll see this error in many more cases where a gem uses C code)

- Easiest way is to install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).
- But Xcode has a lot of extra utilities that you might not need if you wan't only the compilers. There is a project (now supported by Apple) that installs only the command-line tools (various compilers and stuff) called [Commandline tools for Xcode](http://kennethreitz.com/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew.html). Install this (or Xcode) and then try to install the gem.

Comment: I have it, there is gcc etc... problem is with this gem or something. I already found this post http://www.conandalton.net/2010/10/gem-install-mysql-should-be-easy-on-mac.html however this methot not worked for me

Comment: Ah! Had a closer look at the link you've provided. The error in the link and the one you've got are different. Can you paste out what the last bunch of lines say in this file? `/Users/marcinkrzyzanowski/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api` Or better, copy the file in pastebin or gist.github.com and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a pain in the back trying to install mysql from command line, so I just went to the website and got it. Here is the link: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads

Then choose the dmg version and install it.

This is absolutely the answer you did want to receive I bet (same here), but I could not do it otherwise.

I'm on OS X 10.7.4

Comment: I altready tried download mysql and install, however stuck with the very same error. 10.8

Comment: @Marcin sorry I just retried installing and it worked without a problem, but Im on 10.7.4 as I said

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue, so let's see if we can work through it together. I've gone through a ton of Stack Overflow posts, and nothing anyone suggests works.

- XCode  4.6.3 Installed
- Mysql 5.6.12 x64 installed from DMG
- OSX 10.8.4
- Ruby 2.0.0-p195

Mysql installed to **/usr/local/mysql**

Tried to install using the following with no success:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql --   --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib   --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

`sudo find / -name mysql.h` results in
    `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64/include/mysql.h`

**/usr/local/mysql** is a symlink to **/usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64**

I'm going to be working on this until I can get it resolved, so if I come across anything, I'll post it.